# Como retornar todos os registros de uma tabela

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

No meu contexto eu tenho uma tabela de Arquivo, e outra de versão do arquivo, então eu fiz com o entity para retornar um arquivo, e apenas uma versão do arquivo:

```
 internal Arquivo GetArquivo(string termo)
    {
        using (var ctx = new GEDEntities())
        {
            var arquivo = (from arq in ctx.ARQUIVO
                           where arq.ARQUIVO_GUID == termo
                           || arq.XARQUIVO == termo
                           select new Arquivo()
                           {
                               ARQUIVO_GUID = arq.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                               DIRETORIO_GUID = arq.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                               EXTENSAO = arq.EXTENSAO,
                               IS_STREAM = arq.IS_STREAM,
                               TAG = arq.TAG,
                               TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arq.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                               ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arq.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                               URL = arq.URL,
                               XARQUIVO = arq.XARQUIVO,
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
            if (arquivo == null)
                throw new ArquivoException("Arquivo não encontrado");
            arquivo.ArquivoVersoes.Add(GetArquivoVersao(arquivo.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID));
            return arquivo;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arquivoVersaoGuid"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal ArquivoVersao GetArquivoVersao(string arquivoVersaoGuid)
    {
        using (var ctx = new GEDEntities())
        {
            var versao = (from ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO
                          where ver.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID == arquivoVersaoGuid
                          select new ArquivoVersao()
                          {
                              ARQUIVO_GUID = ver.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                              ARQUIVO = ver.ARQUIVO,
                              USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = ver.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID,
                              TAMANHO = ver.TAMANHO,
                              DATAHORA = ver.DATAHORA,
                              ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = ver.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
            if (versao == null)
                throw new ArquivoException("Versão não encontrada");
            return versao;
        }
```

Classe Arquivo

```
public class Arquivo
{
    public Arquivo() 
    {
        ArquivoVersoes = new List<ArquivoVersao>();
    }
    public string ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string XARQUIVO { get; set; }
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public string EXTENSAO { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool IS_STREAM { get; set; }
    public string ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string DIRETORIO_GUID { get; set; }
    public TipoDeArquivo TipoDeArquivo { get; set; }
    public List<ArquivoVersao> ArquivoVersoes { get; set; }
```

Classe ArquivoVersao

```
 public class ArquivoVersao
{    

    public string ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public byte[] ARQUIVO { get; set; }
    public string USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID { get; set; }
    public int TAMANHO { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATAHORA { get; set; }
}
```

Como ficaria um metodo para receber todas as versoes dos aqruivos?

Comment: Você está aqui há bastante tempo. Procure colocar títulos que ajudem identificar o problema. Este título não significa nada. Descreva o problema sucintamente em uma frase curta. Não precisa dizer no título que está usando EF, a *tag* já diz isto.

Comment: alterei,mas nao sei bem especificar esse contexto

Comment: se puder me ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: melhorou, não está ideal, mas vai praticando. Isto ajuda você até pensar melhor no problema, ou quem sabe descrevê-lo melhor para receber ajuda melhor.

Comment: neste caso, é possivel ter apenas um método, que retorne o arquivo e todas as suas versões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode tentar o seguinte:

```
internal ArquivoVersao GetArquivoVersao(string arquivoGuid)
{
    using (var ctx = new GEDEntities())
    {
        var versoes = (
                from ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO
                where ver.ARQUIVO_GUID == arquivoGuid
                select new ArquivoVersao()
                {
                    ARQUIVO_GUID = ver.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO = ver.ARQUIVO,
                    USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = ver.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID,
                    TAMANHO = ver.TAMANHO,
                    DATAHORA = ver.DATAHORA,
                    ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = ver.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID
                }
            ).ToList();
        if (versoes == null)
            throw new ArquivoException("Versão não encontrada");
        return versoes;
    }
}
```

Uma outra opção é alterar o método GetArquivo e remover o GetArquivoVersao:

```
internal Arquivo GetArquivo(string termo)
{
    using (var ctx = new GEDEntities())
    {
        var arquivo = (
            from arq in ctx.ARQUIVO
            join ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO on arq.ARQUIVO_GUID equals ver.ARQUIVO_GUID
            where arq.ARQUIVO_GUID == termo || arq.XARQUIVO == termo
            group ver by new {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arq.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                DIRETORIO_GUID = arq.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                EXTENSAO = arq.EXTENSAO,
                IS_STREAM = arq.IS_STREAM,
                TAG = arq.TAG,
                TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arq.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arq.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                URL = arq.URL,
                XARQUIVO = arq.XARQUIVO,
            } into arqVersoes
            select new Arquivo()
            {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arqVersoes.Key.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                DIRETORIO_GUID = arqVersoes.Key.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                EXTENSAO = arqVersoes.Key.EXTENSAO,
                IS_STREAM = arqVersoes.Key.IS_STREAM,
                TAG = arqVersoes.Key.TAG,
                TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arqVersoes.Key.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arqVersoes.Key.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                URL = arqVersoes.Key.URL,
                XARQUIVO = arqVersoes.Key.XARQUIVO,
                ArquivoVersoes = arquivo.toList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        if (arquivo == null)
            throw new ArquivoException("Arquivo não encontrado");
        return arquivo;
    }
}
```

PS: Codigo não testado.

Comment: explica essa linha pf:  from arq in ctx.ARQUIVO
                join ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO on arq.ARQUIVO_GUID equals ver.ARQUIVO_GUID

Comment: Realizei algumas alterações baseadas nas recomendações do colega @Renan

Comment: ainda da erro de comparação mas da erro na seguinte linha : where arq.ARQUIVO_VERSAO == arquivoVersaoGuid   fala que nao pode comparar com string

Comment: deu certo, funcionou

Comment: ops continua com erro, vou postar a classe arquivo, e arquivoversao

Comment: alterei a pergunta

Comment: é apenas um metodo? e como vou saber se quero 1 versao ou todas?

Comment: Eu prefiro um metodo separado, mas como fica afinal? continua dando erro na comparação ==

Comment: amigo deu tudo certo. valeu

Comment: cara tem como me ajudar aqui

Comment: entra no chat aqui: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20863/discussion-between-war-lock-and-tobymosque

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que seja exatamente como o TobyMosque respondeu, apenas complementando:

Por que não usar FirstOrDefault() nesse caso?

**FirstOrDefault()** retorna o primeiro elemento de uma sequência ou um valor padrão caso não seja encontrado nenhum elemento.

Sendo assim, como você precisa retornar uma lista com todas as versões e não apenas uma, você pode usar o métod **ToList()**, que retornará uma lista de versões.

Por que mudar a assinatura do método?

Você precisa mudar a assinatura do seu método para que ele retorne uma coleção (como uma lista, veja no exemplo abaixo), da forma que está na pergunta irá retornar apenas uma versão:

```
internal List<ArquivoVersao> GetArquivoVersao(string arquivoVersaoGuid)
```

---

> valeu, explica essa linha tambem: explica essa linha pf: from arq in ctx.ARQUIVO join ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO on arq.ARQUIVO_GUID equals ver.ARQUIVO_GUID

O join do LINQ, assim como o join da linguagem SQL, junta elementos de duas coleções com base em alguma condição.

No caso dessa consulta, será uma junção de elementos da tabela ARQUIVO com elementos da tabela ARQUIVO_VERSAO onde o campo ARQUIVO_GUID da tabela de ARQUIVO é igual ao campo ARQUIVO_GUID da tabela ARQUIVO_VERSAO.

Comment: e porque (Guid arquivoGuid) ?? o que é esse guid?

Comment: Foi erro de digitação :-) já ajustei.

Comment: valeu, explica essa linha tambem:  
explica essa linha pf: from arq in ctx.ARQUIVO join ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO on arq.ARQUIVO_GUID equals ver.ARQUIVO_GUID

Comment: Guid é uma estrutura de dados, em outras linguagens ela é conhecida por UUID, basicamente são 16 bytes que podem ser representados por uma string no seguinte formato:
00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF

Comment: from arq in ctx.ARQUIVO join ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO on arq.ARQUIVO_GUID equals ver.ARQUIVO_GUID, é apenas uma união entre os arquivos ARQUIVO e ARQUIVO_VERSAO.
Para o exemplo acima ele realmente é desnecessario.
from ver in ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO seria o suficiente.

Comment: mas da erro na seguinte linha : where arq.ARQUIVO_VERSAO == arquivoVersaoGuid   fala que nao pode comparar com string

Comment: pode atualizar a sua pergunta, colocando a estrutura das classes ArquivoVersao e Arquivo?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20863/discussion-between-war-lock-and-tobymosque).

Comment: Estranho, não vi no código da sua pergunta essa linha que você falou que esta dando erro.

Comment: vai no chat agora,